# Can probability be used to calculate (any?) effect size measurement?

Tags: meta-analysis

For example, some studies report the probability of survival, on a scale of 0-1, with SE, and sample sizes for two treatments, rather than the mean and SD. Is there a sensible way to use the probabilities directly or convert to a useful format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to talk about effect size for survival analysis is through [Cox proportional hazards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model) or [accelerated failure time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_failure_time_model) models (though others exist too). In Cox PH models, the hazard ratio is used to describe effect size. This is by far the most popular approach to my knowledge. In AFT models, the ratio of time-to-event describes the effect size.

Both of these models make assumptions that are not necessarily correct. Said assumptions should be tested and if violated this should *at least* be mentioned (though it is often ommitted).

The problem with other, more traditional measures is that parts of the information are lost. Some examples:

- odds ratios/relative risk/logistic regression: ignores when events occurred in time
- comparing mean time-to-event using t tests or linear regression: ignores censoring

[These powerpoint slides](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CFEQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pitt.edu%2F~super4%2F33011-34001%2F33051-33061.ppt&ei=2i2gUqLYEeWW0QXW4ID4Cg&usg=AFQjCNE2Owl8oZHVM5qBbh14kkqn8QGAFw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.d2k) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I have marked this as correct - but I needed to be more clear in my question... The study in question does not apply a survival model, (or either of these models), just reports the probability of an event. Example: Sighting probability of a bird, in sampled and controlled areas, with 95% Conf Int, and sample size. I imagine one cannot treat this as means to calculate Hedges g?